# How to access beanstalk worker default queue_url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-sqs

I see `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/cfn-metadata-cache.json` has `queue_url` inside.

I have a long-running task which is failed by `nginx 504 timeout`

So I think to split this task into smaller ones and publish in SQS back, to pull by `sqsd`.

Unfortunately, with this approach, I have to set *ENV* variable with the queue name.

This is not okay, since EB already have that option. 2 sources of the same config aren't robust enough.
[image]

Is there any straightforward way to use queue without parsing such JSON file?

Answer (score 2):

The **alternative** way is to just use EB **AWS API** to get the queue names. For example, using AWS CLI:

**WorkerQueue**:

```
aws elasticbeanstalk describe-environment-resources  --environment-name Fff-env --query "EnvironmentResources.Queues[?Name=='WorkerQueue'].URL" --output text
```

**Worker DLQ:**

```
aws elasticbeanstalk describe-environment-resources  --environment-name Fff-env --query "EnvironmentResources.Queues[?Name=='WorkerDeadLetterQueue'].URL" --output text
```

Comment: I mean, how to use it from code :) Any hidden env vars or files to read

Comment: @kAldown You wrote that you don't want to use `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/cfn-metadata-cache.json` nor use env variables. So i'm not aware of any other options.

Comment: I wasn't sure cfn-metadata-cache is the only file describing eb configuration.

Comment: @kAldown There are others in `/etc` but you still have to parse them. But the thing is that your app on worker EB should not interact with the queue. This is job for `sqsd`, not your app. Therefore, its not easy to get the queue url.

Comment: Sure thing. But for some reason `.ebextension/nginx/conf.d/timeout.conf` won't change overall nginx configuration. So I have to split tasks into smaller ones. How? By sending a message back to Q. AWS is a nightmare =\

Comment: @kAldown If you use Amazon Linux 2, then `.ebextension/nginx/conf.d/timeout.conf` is incorrect file to use for nginx settings, explaining why it does not work.

Comment: Thanks. Lost so much time to figure it out. Ending up doing this https://gist.github.com/moea/01afc49934730e4d240e#file-nginx-config

Comment: I mean. It's not what I was looking for. But the discussion was really helpful. Thanks.